# HTMLAgilityPack parse in the InnerHTML

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

```
<div>
<b>Token1</b>
Token2
<b>Token3</b>
</div>
```

I try to extract Token2 from the div

I manage to get Token1 and Token3 with :

```
HtmlNodeCollection headerFooter = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div//b");
```

How can I extract directly Token2 with HTMLAgilityPack ?

One dirty option is to replace Token1 and Token2 by string.empty in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").InnerText, but I imagine it can been done in more clean way with HTMLAgilityPack...

Answer (score 6):

The text is in the text nodes; so you should be able to look at "//div/text()" and concatenate:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlTextNode node in
      doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div/text()"))
{
    sb.Append(node.Text.Trim());
}
string s = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Even using text() I will have Token1 and Token3.

Comment: No you won't... unless you do //text() or //div/*/text(); //div/text() returns *only* those directly under the divs. Or for a specific element, SelectNodes("text()")

Comment: Or in other words... try it ;-p