# Getting innerHTML of TD tag with Regular Expression

Tags: c#, regex, html-parsing, grouping

I want to parse HTML with regular expression. Here is the html source code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to take innerHTML of TD tags in a collection.

PS: I don't know how many TD tags will be exist in the html source.
I think this can be done with REGEX GROUPING. Please add explanations in your answer about grouping and your code.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Probably easier to parse as XML rather than using Regex (somebody will no doubt post a link to the "DONT USE REGEX TO PARSE HTML" answer)

Comment: You really want to think twice, no, three times about parsing HTML with a regex. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454.

Comment: ..and a good follow-up might be that you should look into using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead (also available via Nuget). Here is an example: [HTMLAgilityPack parse in the InnerHTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346144/htmlagilitypack-parse-in-the-innerhtml).

Answer (score 3):

Regex is a search tool, and is not suitable for parsing HTML (or any programming language for that matter)
If you ever want to parse HTML [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is probably the way to go.